# ng-cloak not solving the initial flicker issue with Angularjs UI Bootstrap tabset

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I am using Angularjs UI Bootstrap Tab set. In order to avoid initial flicker issue, with tab names, I am using ng-cloak, but surprisingly still the initial flicker is appearing. I guess it is due to the large html content I have. Can any one suggest any fix for this?
The following is my tab set, and tab names are causing initial flicker issue.

```
<body >
  <div class="splash" ng-controller="ApplicationController" ng-cloak>
    <p>Please wait while loading!</p>
</div>
<div id="content" data-ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="init()"  ng-cloak>
    <tabset>
        <tab ng-repeat="eachTab in chartsTabs" heading="{{eachTab.tabName}}" select="createChartsPerTab(recordsSet, eachTab)"> </tab>
    </tabset>
</div>
</body>
```

The following is my piece of code using ng-cloak:

```
<div id="splash" data-ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="init()"  ng-cloak>
```

And in my custom css file I have :

```
[ng:cloak], 
[ng-cloak], 
[data-ng-cloak], 
[x-ng-cloak], 
.ng-cloak, 
.x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also put a ng-cloak directive on your other container. I.e.

```
<body ng-controller="ApplicationController">
    <!-- Please note that this splash is a separate div beside the main div -->
    <div class="splash" ng-cloak>
        <p>Please wait while loading!</p>
    </div>
    <!-- and here comes your content div -->
    <div id="content" ng-controller="ContentController" ng-cloak>
        <!-- everything else here -->
    </div>
</body>
```

and your custom css looks like:

```
/* this css rule is to hide everything with the ng-cloak directive */
[ng-cloak] {
    display: none !important;
}

/* this css rule displays the splash element if the ng-cloak directive is active */
[ng-cloak].splash {
    display: block !important;
}

/* just style your splashscreen */
.splash {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ededed;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: none;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 5000;
 }

.splash p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question,  I am applying ng-cloak for the full application in the div, immediately after body tag

Comment: but, your splash should be a different element than your content element as you can see in my example. put a div with your loading stuff before your main content.

Comment: I have edited my question as per your directions, but it does not solve the problem. What happening now is, first I am getting a message 'Please wait while loading!' for a fraction of sec and then tab name flickering continuing for another 1 sec.

Comment: Is there anyway to replace heading="{{eachTab.tabName}}", with ng-bind? I am not sure whether it will solve the problem ..

Comment: hm, I made a little investigation. where are you loading your javascript files? if they are at the beginning, there could be a flicker. If I had the scripts at the end of the html page, the splash image was shown as long as angular wasn't available.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is, as your tab name is seen with flicker effect, the issue is at the  directive level, you can modify your directive tab's template html to include a ng-cloak wherever the name of tab appears.

Comment: I did not understand fully, that tab directive,  I am using is directly from Angularjs UI Bootstrap. Could you please provide some sample code in line of your solution?

Answer (score 0):

**ng-cloack** could not be used until the angularjs library is not loaded completeley.
try to work with the directive **ng-include** because it will only show the content after angularjs library is loaded and everything is compiled.

for example:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
  <body ng-cloak ng-controller="YourController">
    <div class="container">
      <div ng-include="'templateWhichIsCompletelyCompiled.html'"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```